# Rails Stylesheet not styling view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I don't understand why my charges stylesheet is not being picked up appropriately. 
Any styling I do in charges.css.scss do not affect my view in any way.

application.css

```
 *
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require_self    
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require front
 *= require lists
 *= require tasks
 *= require lightbox
 */
```

charges.css.scss

```
// Place all the styles related to the charges controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/

.row_form {
    background-color: red;
}
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="container row_form" style="width:990px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span1 offset3">
       <h2></h2>
       <%= render '/charges/new' %>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `_new` is a popout payment form using stripe.js

Only inline styling is working and it doesn't pick up any bootsstrap classes either. What am I not understanding here? Also, I tried including `*= require_tree .` and `*= require charges` in the manifest to no avail.

UPDATED WITH HTML SOURCE

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container row_form" style="width:990px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span1 offset3">
       <h2></h2>
       <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/charges" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="dvlHeyYvCVfMox/UilOaNoPmT+eO3Z7PuMgE3kXpDPU=" /></div>
  <article>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $number</span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="pk_test_3ZFJmvwy4tgn2XUPwUsL7mZQ"
          data-description="Continued Full User Acess"
          data-amount="integer">
  </script>
</form>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

check the followings

1. does you app runs on development mode ?
2. try `rake assets:clean` and *re-start* the sever
3. check your style sheet is updated (via the source of the html page)

hope one of this should get you going :)

Comment: 1. Yes this is in dev environment

Comment: 1. Yes this is in dev environment 2. the source doesnt show the stylesheet but I'm not sure why (updated answer with source). 3. Trying rake asset:clean did not work unfortunately

Comment: This is what I have working now, but I know it is not best practice implementation. In my charges controller new action I have `render :layout => false` and have included all the html of my `app/layouts/application.html.erb` in the `new.html.erb` view. I'm still not sure why it is not loading without this hack, please advise if you have any insight. thanks

Comment: ah, thats the reason :), when you say layout => false, it will not render your application layout, try adding  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %> in to your page (which you showed in the answer) , should work :)